# How do I create an anonymous function that doesn't generate a void function problem in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I create an inline function to fix this error:
`The argument type 'void Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function`.

Consider the following code:

```
                Switch(value: _showChart, onChanged: () {   //this generates the error
                  setState(() {
                    _showChart = value;
                  });
                },)
```

If I extracted it to a function it would look something like this, but I don't want to do that:

```
  VoidCallback? onSwitch(val){
    setState(() {
      _showChart = val;
    });
  }
```

Is there a way to do that inline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onChanged:` contains a value parameter.

You are missing a typo, the `value` parameter.  It will be,

```dart
Switch(
  value: true,
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
     _showChart = value;
      });
  },
),
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I thought 'value'  was automatically available.